# Next/image is serving incorrect images from the cache

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am encountering an issue with image caching in my Next.js v13.0.0 project deployed on AWS. Despite having a correct image src, the production server is serving the wrong images.

I've followed a solution from a closed GitHub issue [issue_link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/23518) that addresses a same problem, but it hasn't resolved my issue. I've installed `sharp` and removed `./next` folder and then build it again but the issue persists.

Here are the details of my setup:

- Next.js version: v13.0.0
- Deployment platform: AWS

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this image caching problem on AWS. Thank you!